# Is this SE an appropriate site to ask questions about fuel cells?

Tags: discussion

On occasion, I have questions about generating electricity, which would clearly make these sort of questions applicable for this SE. On the other hand, some of the questions I have involve generating electricity using fuel cells, which may make questions more applicable for the chemistry SE. Which site would be more appropriate for fuel cell-related questions, around the electrical design/electricity generation aspects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider that either may be appropriate depending on which aspects are being asked about. For example Lithium Ion battery questions are common on this site, with the cell largely (but not totally) being treated as a black-box with certain defined characteristics. If the question related to chemistry, anode or cathode materials, intercalation, electrolytes and similar then chemistry SE would be better.

So too with fuel cells, which are similar to secondary batteries in the manner which they straddle the EE and chemical divide.